AWS - How to give an IAM Identity user access to console
I want to create a user with to access the AWS console. In the past, I would have just created an IAM user, but AWS now recommends creating an "IAM Identity".
Following AWS's recommendations I created an IAM Identity. Since there is nowhere on the IAM Identity page to give console access to the user, I went back to the IAM page where the only option was to to create a new user.
When I click the radio button that gives the user console access, it gives me the option to "Specify a user in Identity Center".
Specify a user in Identity Center
When I click "Next" I get this popup and I click "Manage in Identity Center"
Manage in Identity Center
This just takes me to the Identity Center and the workflow ends. I can click on users and select the user but there is no way to continue the process of giving them console access.
Basically AWS is just sending me around in circles. What am I missing?

Can you point us to where AWS makes this recommendation?

I just created an IAM user and moved on with my life, so this question is no longer important. I did work out that you have to create an Identity group and then give that group permissions and then add the Identity to that group, but I still couldn't see how to give the group console access and I don't have any more time to waste on AWS and it's convoluted systems.

As per my screenshot, it's when you create a new IAM User and click the "Provide user access to the AWS Management Console" checkbox.

Identity Center is used with SSO. It's a good idea for companies that have a central directory service (eg Active Directory). But if you're not a big company, then 'normal' IAM is fine.

IAM Identity works like a wrapper around an AWS account you choose. It allows you to configure permissions each user must have access to, those actions will happen on the AWS account you selected.
In my case, I had to click the permission policy name I attached to the user. This opened the AWS management console.

The official documentation is rough here.. hopefully this helps others.
Create the User in AWS Identity Center
This is pretty straight forward. You will need to be in the AWS Identity Center. The checkbox from AWS IAM will redirect you here.
Make sure this new user has appropriate permission through groups & account access
For this you will want to create a group (e.g. Admins) and a permission set (e.g. AdminPolicy). Then on the Account listing heirarchy you can assign the Account the Group and Permission Set. This gives access to these groups and permission sets to that account. Note here we mean 'AWS Account' not the user you just created.
Once that's done, you can assign the identity center user you are trying to give console access to to that group and they should have access to that account with the permission level provided by the groups permission set... still with me?
Access the AWS Access Portal for the user
Once the user was invited in previous step they will receive a welcome email to setup their password and access their AWS Access Portal. This will show the accounts they have access to. Clicking on the account will.. TADA take you into the AWS Management Console where they will only have the ability to access resources according to their permission level..
